# SwiftUI: Animate inserted values to line graph

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created a line graph of a fixed width that takes in "data" (an array of doubles), using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgSfsdeMosM&t=683s). Here is my code:

```
struct ChartView: View {
    
    var data: [Double]
    private let maxY: Double = Double(Constants.maxRange)
    private let minY: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack (spacing: 0) {
            HStack (spacing: 0) {
                chartYAxis
                    .frame(width: 40)
                Divider()
                chartView
                    .background(chartBackground)
                Divider()
            }
            HStack (spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 20)
                chartXAxis
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 300)
        .font(.caption)
        .foregroundColor(Color("TextColor"))
    }
}

extension ChartView {
    
    private var chartView: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Path { path in
                for index in data.indices {
                    
                    let xPosition = geometry.size.width / CGFloat(data.count - 1) * CGFloat(index)
                    
                    let yAxis = maxY - minY
                    let yPosition = (1 - CGFloat((data[index] - minY) / yAxis)) * geometry.size.height
                    
                    if (index == 0) {
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition))
                    }
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition ))
                }
            }
            .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
        }
    }
    
    private var chartBackground: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()
            Spacer()
            Divider()
            Spacer()
            Divider()
        }
    }
    
    private var chartYAxis: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(maxY, specifier: "%.0f")")
            Spacer()
            let midY = (maxY + minY) / 2
            Text("\(midY, specifier: "%.0f")")
            Spacer()
            Text("\(minY, specifier: "%.0f")")
        }
    }
    
    private var chartXAxis: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Text("\(index + 1)")
                if (index < (data.count - 1)) {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The array "data" will append values as per button press by the user, and at any time should have around 2-20 values.

Every time value is appended to "data", I want to animate this change. The animation should not redraw the line from left to right ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62726114/swiftui-animate-each-line-while-drawing-a-line-graph-using-path)) but squeeze the existing line together to make room for the appended value. [Here is a very janky example](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fpythonprogramming.net%2Fstatic%2Fimages%2Fdataviz%2FLive-updating-Matplotlib-graphs.gif&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fpythonprogramming.net%2Fpython-matplotlib-live-updating-graphs%2F&tbnid=XHGEDAWho3d_qM&vet=12ahUKEwjsmbrVofn2AhW3BrcAHUdMCMIQMygLegUIARCNAg..i&docid=r_mpLC64m5ey-M&w=870&h=588&q=line%20graph%20update%20animation&hl=en&client=safari&ved=2ahUKEwjsmbrVofn2AhW3BrcAHUdMCMIQMygLegUIARCNAg) of how I want the graph to work. However, I would like the changes to be smoother, similar to [this example](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fd3-graph-gallery.com%2Fimg%2Fgraph%2Fline_select.gif&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fd3-graph-gallery.com%2Fline.html&tbnid=UzM3hIRKxGAlnM&vet=12ahUKEwjsmbrVofn2AhW3BrcAHUdMCMIQMygJegUIARCHAg..i&docid=OkPzgsUpErQfXM&w=480&h=480&q=line%20graph%20update%20animation&hl=en&client=safari&ved=2ahUKEwjsmbrVofn2AhW3BrcAHUdMCMIQMygJegUIARCHAg).

I want the graph frame to remain the same size with appended values to "data", not to scroll to add new values as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339479/xcode-dynamic-live-update-line-chart).

I have looked at some examples of animatable vectors in line graphs, but none address this problem I am having.

Does anyone know if there is any software or method I could use to achieve this? I am fairly new to Swift, so I am hoping this is possible.